# CI bonfire + Code duplication in different context

Tags: codeigniter, dry, bonfire

I just want to clarify this doubt. I might be wrong. I've learnt in OOP we should not repeat codes through out the classes according to the **DRY** principle. However, if I checked the admin settings context and the public context check boxes, bonfire will create two controllers in the module/controllers folder (in this case settings.php and mymodule.php). I can see the functions have been repeated. I feel like, I could just use one common controller for CRUD and load different public and admin views, or even for other context as well. Can some one help me to understand this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is also the Single Responsibility Principle. A class should have only one reason to change. This is likely to support using two controllers. You can remove the common code into another class if that helps.

Comment: Thanks David! Maybe we can put common CRUD functions into a super controller class and extend it to settings.php and mymodule.php. :D

Comment: Yes, either that or inject a class into both that does that.